# How to create a 2D animated sequence all in code in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I would like to create an animated 2D sequence (in future 3D as well) using [Unity](https://unity.com/solutions/film-animation-cinematics). From the website, I can see that the platform also targets the Cinema industry, so Unity can apparently be used not just for games.

#### My requirements

I can see that Unity provides timelines and all that stuff to create animated sequences, however I would like to develop my sequences all in code (C#):

- Placing the objects in the scene procedurally.
- Moving objects in the scene procedurally.
- Creating splines and other shapes procedurally in the scene.
- Moving cameras in the scene procedurally.
- Record from different cameras and produce a final video (always in code).

For example, library [manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim) allows you to do all this in Python. But I would like to do the same in Unity and C#.

Can this be achieved with Unity? Do you have any examples you can point me to or you can write down as an answer?

#### Basic example

As a valid answer, can you give an answer where you show a simple code which animates a rectangle and exports the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have tons of libraries to achieve the animation process, popular one is [DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/).

"Video Exportation" is a tricky field (at least for me) and what I really like to use is [Unity Recorder](https://unitytech.github.io/unity-recorder/manual/index.html) free plugin. Really easy to use.

This plugins takes me to talk about timelines. The fact that you want "procedural stuffs" do not have to directly collide with timeline use. In fact timelines can be coded as you can see [here](https://blogs.unity3d.com/es/2019/06/25/how-to-create-custom-timeline-markers/).

So if we go with your desired example (and my desired answer check!), I'll take for granted that at least your using Unity Recorder for the video exportation.

1. Instantiate the rectangle

You can do this by a multiple ways, if you have a prefab of how you want the rectangle you can automatically instantiate the prefab, but you can also create the rectangle from a primitive cube like:

```
private void Start()
{
    //Instantiate rectangle
    GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);//First create a cube
    cube.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);              //Set it's position in the 3D scene
    cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.5f, 1, 1);            //modify his size to achieve a rectangle-style
}
```

2. Animate the rectangle

Again, you can do this by a multiple ways, using the [animator controller system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html) recording clips, or using the Timeline tool, or using the library mentionated before (DOTween). But of caurse you can move it programatically. My advice is to use [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to achieve that, one example (really basic) could be this code, where the rectangle will move 10 units to the right.

```
IEnumerator moveRectangle10Positions()
{
    while(rectangle.transform.position.x <= 10)
    {
        rectangle.transform.position = new Vector3(rectangle.transform.position.x + 1, rectangle.transform.position.y, rectangle.transform.position.z);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
}
```

This really looks clunky but keep in mind that you're working with vectors and that kind of maths, so you can use [Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) calculations to smooth movements, etc.

3. Finally, export the video

As I said I assume that you have installed the plugin I mentioned (Unity Recorder). Then you all have to do is just set the parameters of how you want the video (duration, frames per second, format, etc) and press play. You can do that with Timeline too.

Comment: This looks very promising. Thanks for going through every single point man, truly appreciate it. Let me try all this stuff!!!

Comment: Glad to help Andry! If you don't know how to put it all together (I don't know your experience with Unity) just put a comment and I'll do my best to keep updating the answer ;) Another think to keep in mind (as you're question is focused to filming) I'll recommend you to keep a look to Cinemachine (https://unity.com/es/unity/features/editor/art-and-design/cinemachine)!

Comment: Cinemachine seems interesting. TBH I saw this but stopped at the first lines in the doc as I thought this was specific for games in order to keep the camera anchored to a character... But it seems like I was very wrong.

I have got a little experience in game making with Unity, so I think I should manage putting all together :) Docs might help me as well. I won't hesitate reaching out to you here in case. Thanks again, nice answer, if this works out I'm gonna mark it of course.